# get python arrray on java program

Tags: java, python, arrays

Im trying to use python to write a set of coordinates to an excel sheet and then read it in on a java program

I tried using the following code but it didnt write to my excel sheet

```
img = cv2.imread("lines.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 150)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 30, maxLineGap=250)


row = 0
for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[0]:

cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 3)

text =  "{}, {}".format((x1,y1),(x2,y2))
print(text)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('line.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()



worksheet.write(row,0,"{}".format((x1,y1)));
worksheet.write(row,1,"{}".format((x2,y2)));
row+=1
```

Comment: what are you expecting the output to look like here `for col, data in enumerate((x1,y1)):
 worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)` enumerate((x1,y1)) will give you `[(1,x1),(2,y1)]`  ?

Comment: @corn3lius looking for an output of  ID, (x1,y1), (x2,y2)

Comment: what is ID, index?

Comment: @corn3lius ID should just be incremental from each set of coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Added a little refactoring : try this.

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 30, maxLineGap=250)
row = 0
for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[0]:

    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 3)

    text =  "{}, {}".format((x1,y1),(x2,y2))
    print(text)

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('arrays.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    #for col, data in enumerate((x1,y1)):
    #    worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)
    # This isn't doing what you think it should.  

    worksheet.write(row,0,"{}".format((x1,y1)));
    worksheet.write(row,1,"{}".format((x2,y2)));
    row+=1
    # this will add each tuple point in each cell. like
    # "(1,2)","(4,5)"
    # "(7,8)","(9,0)" ...

worksheet.close()
```

Comment: sorry I took a while away to reply, I implimented your code but it didnt write any data to my actual excel sheet and only printed the first set of coordinates